# Dynamics CRM Javascript making form read only -TypeError: control.getDisabled is not a function

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

Attempting to make the price list form and price items form read only and using the below java script however keep getting the following error; *One of the scripts for this record has caused an error. For more details, download the log file.
TypeError: control.getDisabled is not a function at makeFieldsReadOnly*

Using Dynamics CRM 2016 and this JS runs on load of the form

```
function onLoad() {
    var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();

    if (formType == 2)
        makeFieldsReadOnly(); }


function makeFieldsReadOnly() {
    var controls = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get();
    for (var i in controls) {
        var control = controls[i];
        if (!control.getDisabled()) {
            control.setDisabled(true);
       }
    } }
```

Any suggestions on why this may be failing , working fine in CRM 2011?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all the controls you are iterating over can be disabled and thus the code is failing. It throws an error when it tries to execute `getDisabled` on a control, which does not have this function declared.

This can be fixed by checking if the necessary functions exist on the control first:

```
function onLoad() {
    var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();

    if (formType == 2)
        makeFieldsReadOnly(); }


function makeFieldsReadOnly() {
    var controls = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get();
    for (var i in controls) {
        var control = controls[i];
        if (control.getDisabled && control.setDisabled && !control.getDisabled()) {
            control.setDisabled(true);
       }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This seems to have stopped the error from appearing , however the fields are still editable

Comment: The `makeFieldsReadOnly` function works just fine for me on CRM2016. Is your code executed via the standard onLoad event-handler of a CRM form?